# How to run PHP code in Sublime Text 2

Tags: php, sublimetext2

I am very new to Sublime text 2. I have just started using this and know nothing about it. I want to work on PHP. I have built a system 'php'. After choosing 'php' build system I am creating a new file and writing PHP code with just a single echo line and trying to run it. Everytime it is giving my this error

[image]

By default Sublime Text 2 saved in C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2

and the path where automatically files are being saved is
C:\Users\SM Ahmed\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User

What should I do that makes my code run succesfully

Comment: Maybe because `sublime` is `text-editor` and not an `interpreter` for `php`, have you installed `php` as well? if not get `php` from : http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: Offtopic to the question but, you could download Sublime 3. :D

Comment: But clicking on "Build" result should be shown in Console.. Right?

Comment: posting the config file of your build system might help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

While traditionally PHP scripts are run by web servers, it is possible to run them through Sublime. To set up a webserver, I suggest you to read this: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html

It will get you started on how to setup a local server and 'run' PHP.

If you want to run PHP from your Sublime Text 2/3 console you should go to:

```
Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...
```

and then edit the file like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["/path/to/php", "$file"]
}
```

where `/path/to/php` is something like `/usr/local/bin/php` on Linux/OS X or `C:/WAMP/bin/php.exe` on Windows (make sure to use forward slashes `/`). Save the file as `Packages/User/PHP.sublime-build` where `Packages` is the folder opened when you select `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. Next, click on `Tools -> Build System -> PHP` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to run your script (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> on a Mac). You should see the output, if any, in the build console that opens.

Be sure there aren't any **errors** in your PHP and also be sure that PHP is **configured correctly**!

Comment: I use something like this just to run a syntax check on PHP code, using the -l lint option for php. I have `"cmd": ["php", "-l", "$file"],`

Comment: @Liam "-l" is for linting (syntax check) only. Does not show the output.

Answer (score 3):

As a ref and an example for Ubuntu users, that works well if you need to simply check PHP syntax in current file that you opened;

Create a file in `/home/$USER/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/PHP - Check Syntax.sublime-build` and put in it.

```
{
    "cmd": ["php", "-l", "$file"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to give full path with .exe file like below

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\iis express\\PHP\\v7.2\\php.exe", "$file"]
}
```