# How to display PHP webpage using Sublime Text (3)?

Tags: php, html, sublimetext3

I have tried following this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322758/how-to-run-php-code-in-sublime-text-2), unfortunately this only displays the code being executed rather than showing how a HTML page with embedded PHP would look like.

What I want is someway to execute `index.php` file to view how that website would look and behave. With `index.html` in sublime text this is easy enough with `right click` and then `Open in Browser`. How can I do this with PHP files and Sublime Text 3 or an alternative method with other software?

Comment: You need apache/nginx and php installed.

Comment: Do you have a webserver with a PHP interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [PHP web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) (for PHP >= 5.4.0) which you can run with the following command from the directory where you PHP file is (note that `PHP.exe`'s directory must be added to the `PATH` environment variable if you are on Windows)

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

A simpler solution would be to install something like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) which has Apache (A web server) already configured with PHP. once installed you can put your PHP files inside the `htdocs` directory and you'll be able to execute your PHP code by going to `http://localhost/yourfile.php`.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm answering under the assumption that you already have Apache/PHP running locally.**

I think the most popular solution for SublimeText3 is to use the [SideBarEnhancements](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SideBarEnhancements) package. You can use [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation) to install it. After you install SideBarEnhancements, you can right click on a PHP file in the sidebar and click "Open In Browser" to see how it would look after being parsed by PHP. You might have to right-click on your project and go to `Project -> Edit Project URLs` to configure the paths to your project. When you select "Edit Project URLs" a new file will open named "SideBarEnhancements.json" where you can configure your paths.

You should put the following code inside the file.

```
{
    "/path/to/your/document/root":{
        "url_testing":"http://localhost",
        "url_production":"http://www.example.com"
    },
}
```

Comment: Sublime Text 3 only supports one mapping from file system to URL? What if we work with many websites?

Answer (score 0):

To Directly run the PHP web page in browser using Sublime-text you can make a build-system which will run the PHP file in the browser.
I'm assuming you have `apache/nginx` installed in your system.
Make a build file using **Tools**->**Build System**->**New Build System**.
Copy the following code in the file and Save.

```
    {
    "shell_cmd":"firefox \"localhost/$file_base_name.php\"", 
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "embedding.php",
    "variants": 
   }
```

Your PHP file should be saved in the Server root folder.
Press `Ctrl+B` to display file in the browser.

Comment: apache/nginx will do nothing if you do not have PHP as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure Apache HTTP Server on your local computer. Depending on what type of OS your computer is running, you may already have it - but most people use [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/) or WAMP or some graphic interface to administer it.

From there, you'd use a local port (usually localhost:8888) to view the file in your browser.

You can use [Browser Refresh](https://gcollazo.github.io/BrowserRefresh-Sublime/) to save and also refresh the page.

You can also use something like [CodeKit](https://codekitapp.com/) to watch your files and automatically inject the styles or refresh the page.