# cannot view in browser php files sublime 3

Tags: xampp, sublimetext3

I don't know how to run a file in sublime. I have installed View in Browser but after I pressed it nothing happens. I ve seen some solutions and one of them was to edit the project something like:

```
{
"C:/xampp/htdocs":{
    "url_testing":"http://localhost",
    "url_production":"http://localhost"
}
}
```

but when I run it in the browser the url is:

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/hello.php
```

How to resolve this?
When I run it from the folder htdocs it's ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run PHP code in Sublime Text 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25322758/how-to-run-php-code-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I put { "cmd": ["C:/xampp/php/php.ini", "$file"]} and when I run it it says that [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
[cmd: ['C:/xampp/php/php.ini', '']]

Comment: That's not what the linked answer tells you to do.

Comment: Thats what I have understood from it. The $file should be the file that I want to run? If you offer to give me an answer please help me.

Comment: "where /path/to/php is something like /usr/local/bin/php on Linux/OS X or C:/WAMP/bin/php.exe on Windows (make sure to use forward slashes /). " I have no idea where you got php.ini from, it is not mentioned in the answer. I can't help you read.

Answer (score 0):

try this guide:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/preview-in-localhost/

Then edit your JSON file with this:

```
{
"C:/xampp/htdocs":{
    "url_testing":"http://localhost//",
    "url_production":"http://localhost//"
    }
}
```

I was able to run the code by right-clicking the file > Open in Browser > Default.